# JS появление текста снизу

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать, чтобы текст плавно появлялся снизу на javascript или jquery. Функция fadeIn просто плавно появляется текст, а мне нужно, чтобы при этом он еще и выезжал снизу вверх

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, пожалуйста:
[выложил на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkbA2/).

HTML

```
<button id="action_handler">Старт</button>
<div id="action_element">123</div>
```

CSS

```css
#action_element{
    display:none;
    opactity: 0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:0px;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

JS

```
$("#action_handler").click(function(){
  $("#action_element").fadeIn(600).animate({
      opacity: 1.0,
      height: "40px",
      display:"toggle",
 }, { duration: 3500, queue: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jqeury animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[jquery slideUp](http://jquery-docs.ru/effects/slideup/)

[jqueryui effects](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)